# Question about the terminology "topological invariant" in Engelking's General Topology book

Tags: general-topology

In Engelking's General topology book, (2nd page 34) he states as follows: After some paraphrasing,

> Let $\mathcal M$ be a class of continuous mappings. A property $P$ of a topological space is an invariant of class $\mathcal M$ if $P$ is preserved by surjective mappings in the class $\mathcal M$.

On the other hand, [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_property) considers topological invariant as a synonym for topological property. However, not all continuous surjective maps are homeomorphisms, so according to Engelking's definition, $P$ being a topological property is a stronger condition.

My question is, are there any standard notation? or terminology on this? Any comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invariance is a property of a kind of mapping: a (topological) property can be preserved by $\mathcal{M}$ as the "continuous maps", "open continuous maps" and "closed continuous maps" or "perfect maps" or "quotient maps" and Engelking proves a lot of theorems in his text about properties being an invariant or (more rarely) an inverse invariant of such classes of maps. "Topological property" he uses just as Wikipedia does: an invariant of homeomorphisms, so something a space (or really a class of spaces) can have. If $P$ is a topological property it need not be an invariant of any of the above-mentioned classes of maps, except (by definition) homeomorphisms. All properties of spaces discussed in his book are topological properties and he sometimes explicitly proves it (e.g. after defining a Čech-complete space or a realcompact space, where this is not as immediate..). Then he often devotes times to study different (inverse) invariances under mappings and also closedness of the property when taking constructions like products, subspaces, sums, quotients etc., also discussing some (counter)examples. It's quite systematic that way.

To me the invariance (under maps) idea is a lens or guide to look at results to prove or disprove.